# Use of enums in Java API

Tags: enums, java

Could you point me out to a class, from official Java API that has a good use of enums ?
I could not find any specific class.

Does the Java API incorporates enums in their classes at all?

Comment: Note that enums where only introduced in Java 5 and a lot of the API already existed at that point. So many  places that *should* have used enums don't do so, because they didn't want to change the API after the fact. Usually only newer APIs use enums.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are 328 enum classes defined in the JRE 7. I suggest you read the [Enum Types tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

A simple one I have used is [java.nio.AccessMode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/nio/file/AccessMode.java).

An enum worth understanding is [Thread.State](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html)

A more interesting one is [java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.java)

An example of a class which IMHO would be an `enum` but predates them is [ByteOrder](http://www.docjar.org/html/api/java/nio/ByteOrder.java.html) See Joachim's comment above.

Comment: NIO has several interesting ones. [`LinkOption`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/LinkOption.html) (and its uses) is an interesting one.

Comment: @Peter - just wondering how you know exact number of enum classes??

Comment: @rai.skumar, yeah, in the java 9 documentation I could only find 93 examples of enums. Are you also counting all the states?

Comment: @OfekGila many of the enum are not public or used internally and not in the Javadoc.  As such the number depends on the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

There are few in Collection API which directly use Enum : EnumSet, EnumMap